# A function $g : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(t) = 0 \Leftrightarrow t \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vectors, orthogonality

I was trying to define a function 
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace
\end{align*}
such that for any two vectors **v** and **w**, 
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) \perp \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}.
\end{align*}
The obvious choice would be $f(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w}$, but of course this doesn't do the job if **v** and **w** are parallel. One solution I thought of, *which doesn't work*, would be to find a function $g : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
g(t) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow t \neq 0.
\end{align*}
and define
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w} + g(|\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w}|)\cdot (\mathbf{v}\times R\mathbf{v})
\end{align*}
where for instance
\begin{align*}
R = \left( \begin{matrix}
0 &-1 &0\\
1 &0 & 0\\
0 &0 &1 \end{matrix} \right)
\end{align*}
is the rotation by $90$ degrees around the $z$-axis.

The point of wanting a function like $f$ was that I didn't want to check cases all the time, ie. check whether my two vectors of the day are parallel or not. For that reason, I'm looking for some $g$ which is not defined conditionally $-$ for example, the indicator function of the singleton $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is not what I'm looking for. On the other hand, a closed form expression would be perfect. Obviously, $g$ can't be continuous, but that's not relevant anyway.

Depending on how you feel about assigning $0^0$ the value $1$, the function $g(t) = 0^t$ would be a possilibity, but I wonder if there are any other (preferably less controversial) choices of such a function $g$. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: I'm just interested in what functions $g$, not defined conditionally, satisfy the condition I mention. The introduction about $f$ is merely what motivated the question about such functions $g$.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that your vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be parallel to $z$ and then the rotation does nothing.

Comment: That's true, of course. Thanks for point it out. The thing is, though, that I'm not as interested in defining the function f anymore - I'm just curious about what functions g satisfy the property I mention. I just included the "story" about f as a motivation for asking the question about g. I'll edit the question to emphasize this

Comment: You want a Dirac delta function. But if you implement this in a computer program, it's an "if" statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "defined conditionally"?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin By "defined conditionally" I mean a function g where the procedure for calculating the output g(t) is different, depending on what the input t is. For example, for the (unconditionally defined) function h(x) = x, the procedure is the same, regardless what the input is. For an indicator function, though, the procedure can be either to return the output 1 or the output 0. The procedure itself for computing the output (and not *just* the output) depends on the input.

Comment: @Andrei I thought of the Dirac distribution as well, but that's not really a function.

Comment: Frankly, I don't undertstand the downvote...

Comment: Sure. But I don't know anything else that is zero when $t\ne 0$

Comment: @TeddantheTerran I'd argue that with h(x)=x we have infinitely many of those conditions. Question really doesn't make much sense to me